# usb keyboard needs unplug/plug every BIOS boot to skip keyboard error or no keyboard present What cause this?

Tags: usb, keyboard, bios

Every BIOS boot ,I get keyboard error or no keyboard present on BIOS.I need unplug/plug to skip this.After I unplug and plug all USB device,the problem solved.What cause this?Does my USB OK?

Comment: It seems as though you have an early BIOS which does not support USB properly. Try updating to the latest version. If you have no problems once your OS is running, it is unlikely that there is anything wrong with your USB.

Comment: My motherboard is DFI DK P45 T2RS PLUS,BIOS is D45PD105 which is the latest BIOS.

Comment: I have had similar problems with USB keyboards. My best solution was to use a USB-PS2 converter and side-step the issue.

Comment: I don't have USB-PS2 converter,and USB unstale really annoying.

Comment: They used to give them away bundled with PS2 keyboards and mouses. I imagine they are still available for a few pence.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling USB controllers may fix this issue

Use the Mouse

================

First, please disconnect all USB devices and then perform the following steps:

1. Click "Start" button, type “devmgmt.msc” (without quotation marks) in the “Search” bar and press "Enter". Click “Continue” if necessary.
2. In Device Manager, double click to expand "Universal Serial Bus controllers", right click on the Host Controller, click "Uninstall" and click "OK".
3. Repeat the step 2 to uninstall all items under "Universal Serial Bus controllers".

Then, restart your computer and Windows 7 will reinstall all USB controllers automatically. once it is done check the reported issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is keyboard not recognized by BIOS before OS.OS isn't load so is not the driver problem

Comment: So you have tried the above steps???

Comment: In fact BIOS I set Halt On to No Errors,and I can use keyboard in OS perfectly.But then I can't enter BIOS.After I unplug and plug all USB device,I can enter BIOS,I wonder if my USB has problem.

Comment: Try running the fix it with trouble shooting usb problems from the following link http://support2.microsoft.com/mats/windows_usb_diagnostics

Comment: Thank you,anyway usb work properly.But I still don't know the reason.